# Delphi use of CopyRect from bmp to image

Tags: image, delphi, canvas

I have such code

```
source.Picture.LoadFromFile(fName);  
buffer.Assign(source.Picture.Bitmap);     
buffer.Canvas.CopyRect(rect(0,0,buffer.Width,buffer.Height), target.Canvas, rect(0,0,buffer.Width,buffer.Height));
```

And it won't work.
There are better ways to load image, but I want to play with them.
The main reason is to load smaller images,
So it's correct to copy canvas rect, but it not shows single pixel...

Objects are initialized and scaled except for target which I want to contain more than one image.
I supose there is no need for writing what types are objects, all needed are classes procedures that shows what are what.

I wonder whats wrong? I tried many ways, but simple nothing.
Please help.

Comment: Please mark-up your delphi code in your question as code! (See WYSIWYG-toolbar-button)

Comment: Why are you making us guess what you are doing

Answer (score 3):

Probably source is `TImage`, buffer is `TBitmap`, target is also `TImage` (you should mention it in your question so we don't have to guess).

In this case, the second line would work only when you load from .BMP because only these have bitmap populated. If you have .png or .jpeg instead, the second line would erase the actual picture and replace it with empty bitmap... Not very intuitive behaviour but it's [documented at least](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap).

To work with arbitrary graphic, you should use [TCanvas.Draw](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Draw) method which in turn calls [TGraphic.Draw()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic.Draw). As you can see from description, it draws the graphic you loaded into the canvas at given rectangle. Something like that:

```
source.Picture.LoadFromFile(fName);
target.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, source.Picture.Graphic);
```

UPD.

If you want to scale arbitrary picture, it could be done this way:

```
source.picture.loadFromFile(fName);
buffer.Width := source.picture.Width;
buffer.Height := source.picture.Height;
buffer.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
buffer.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, source.picture.Graphic);
//so we at last have bitmap containing our image in original size

target.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, NewWidth, NewHeight), buffer.canvas, Rect(0, 0, buffer.Width, buffer.Height));
```

Here NewWidth and NewHeight are image size we want.

By the way, you don't need `source: TImage` if it is just temporary object to load from file. `TPicture` would be enough:

```
var pic: TPicture;

pic := TPicture.Create;
try
  pic.LoadFromFile(fName);
  ...
  buffer.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, pic.Graphic);
finally
  pic.free;
end;
```

Comment: This what i have tried, too. Sure, works - however i cannot resize it this way by setting lower sizes of source image. And what i want is more images on timage. Very correct guess about var types ;) i will try once more because if im not mistaken timage have some resize function. I will write what can be done more. Thanx.

Comment: What image format are you trying to load? Is it loaded the normal way, say, by loading it to TImage at design time?

Comment: mostly jpg this is why i used assign function on tbitmap. hovever it should work after exec. copyrect to timage or tform - any works. I will try whats posted above. Any errors from compiler ;)

Comment: Also i cannot add a breakpoint besause it's not working the way it should so values of bitmap are mostly unknown. on the paper sheet it should work ;)

Comment: @King Arthur See update. Point is: first converting to bitmap of original size, then we can do with bitmap whatever we want, for example, scale it using CopyRect. There is also a way to increase quality of scaled image by calling StretchBLTMode with STRETCH_HALFTONE parameter - the thing which TImage strangely doesn't use most of time. If usual scaling works normally, I can modify an answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Im back again, after hour... i will add only that resize from timage jpeg pictures is impossible by the setsize procedure. Is this procedure above really downscaling images without stretchdraw? I must try it!

Comment: The line source.picture.graphic.Draw(buffer, Rect(0, 0, buffer.Width, buffer.Height); shows compiler error Cannot access protected symbol TGraphic.Draw. what i have tried before target.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, buffer); shows anything.Only target.canvas.draw called with source.Picture.Graphic shows anything (whole image). Is there still a way to overcome such obstacles?

Comment: Without source.picture.graphic.Draw(buffer, Rect(0, 0, buffer.Width, buffer.Height); copyrect shows anything, as above. Default canvas draw is not working. Im thinking about any quality ;) Still please help me!

Comment: @KingArthur my bad, I was on the 'other side' recently, implementing my own TGraphic descendant, so I forgot completely that TGraphic.Draw is protected method which can't be called by user. But you can use TCanvas.Draw(X, Y, Graphic) which just calls this TGraphic.Draw in turn. I've updated my answer once more, try this.

Comment: Finally works, thanks for accurate and fast answer :)

Comment: @KingArthur That's good. Now you can mark this answer as 'accepted', that's how it's done in StackOverflow.

Comment: @KingArthur Click on the checkmark on the left of the answer, it turns green to indicate the acceptance. Also, Please, take [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow. And see other articles in [**help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help)